# How to merge two shapefiles with partial difference in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, merge, fields-attributes

As illustrated below, a copy of the same shapefile was given to two persons who edited them partially by changing the attributes of different features.

I would like to know how to merge the two shapefiles in QGIS into a new one with the differences included?

[image: merge operation]

Following the advice below, I'm still unable to merge the two shapefiles "1" & "2" into one:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use this [approach](http://guides.library.duke.edu/QGIS/Merge)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then to:

> Ensure the correct shapefile type is selected (points, lines, or polygons).
>
> Select the folder where the two (or more) shapefiles you want to merge   are located using the Browse button.
>
> Click browse next to Output shapefile, find your working folder, and   name the output shapefile.

Click OK.

Comment: Thanks, Whyzar! But I only got "merge vector files" in QGIS 2.16 and hopefully that is the same as your suggestion. However, following your suggestion, the merged shape file seems to have overlapping polygons on the same position rather than just one polygon. (don't know how to post images in comments here) Hope you can kindly advise.

Comment: You can click the edit option under your post and then click on the insert image button there to post your screen shot. You won't be able to insert a screen shot here, only a link to an image elsewhere.

Comment: The diagram showing in my post indicates that the two shape files have the same number of polygons in the same shape and position. The only difference between them is the attribute for some of the polygons.

Comment: Once you create the join, you will have all attributes in a single attribute table. There I would recommend editing those columns/fields you don't need any longer. That may be the additional step to get where you want.